# prevent default and add active class only to parent list's links dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want prevent default and add an active class to the parent links of a list in a dropdown menu. The code i have is this:

Markup:

```
<ul class="subNavMobile">
    <li>
        <a href="#">link parent</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="anurl.html">child link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">link parent2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">link parent3</a></li>
</ul>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.subNavMobile > li a').on('click', function (e) {
    var parent = $(this).parent();
    if (!parent.hasClass('active')) {
        parent.parent().find('li.active').removeClass('active');
        parent.addClass('active');
    } else {
        parent.removeClass('active');
    }
});
```

But this is also affectiong to the child list and this is not desired. How do I only add the class and prevent default in just the parents and not in the child? Thank you.

Comment: exactly that DavidThomas. Sorry ^^'

Comment: No problem; that was my *first* thought but it was one of those errors that could either be a typo (as it was) or part of the problem itself...

Comment: Should clicking the child activate the topmost parent?

Comment: No, when clicking a list item in subNavMobile an active class should be added to that list item and be removed in its siblings. The children list items of that list items(parent) shouldn't have this behavior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your selector to:

```
$('.subNavMobile > li > a')
```

Your selector matches `a` that is anywhere inside `.subNavMobile > li`, but you only want the `a` that is a direct child of it.

And to prevent the default, put

```
e.preventDefault();
```

in the function.